# How to display selected country details from data.json file on screen when select a particular country from dropdown

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

Data.Json

```js
{
  "countries": [
    {
      "name": "Australia",
      "continent": "Oceania",
      "rank": 4,
      "id": 1
    },
    {
      "name": "England",
      "continent": "Europe",
      "rank": 5,
      "id": 2
    },
    {
      "name": "Namibia",
      "continent": "Africa",
      "rank": 8,
      "id": 3
      }
      ]
}
```

CountryUI.js

```js
import React from "react";
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import { countryList } from "../actions";

const CountryUi = (props) => {
  useEffect(() => {
    props.countryList();
  }, []);

  const [country, setCountry] = useState("");
  const [selectedCountry, setSelectedCountry] = useState("id");

  const selectHandleChange = (e) => {
    setCountry(e.target.value);
    props.countries.map((countryObject) => {
      console.log(countryObject);
      if (countryObject.id === country) {
        console.log(countryObject, "result");
        setSelectedCountry(countryObject);
        return countryObject;
      }
    });
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <h4>Select Country from below dropdown and get the details</h4>
      <form className="dropdown-form">
        <label className="form-labels">Select Country:</label>
        <select className="select-opt" onChange={selectHandleChange}>
          {props.countries.map((country) => {
            return <option value={country.id}> {country.name} </option>;
          })}
        </select>
      </form>
      <div className="form-labels">Selected:{country}</div>
    </div>
  );
};
const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  return { countries: Object.values(state.countries) };
};
export default connect(mapStateToProps, { countryList })(CountryUi);
```

api/countries.js

```js
import axios from "axios";

export default axios.create({
  baseURL: "http://localhost:8080",
});
```

Action Creator

```js
import countries from "../apis/countries";
import { FETCH_COUNTRYLIST } from "./types";

export const countryList = () => async (dispatch) => {
  const response = await countries.get("/countries");
  dispatch({ type: FETCH_COUNTRYLIST, payload: response.data });
};
```

I have created dropdown list in React. I have used map method in order to get the list of countries which is in data.json file. It's giving me the list of countries in dropdown but I want when I select any country from dropdown list it should give me all the details which is in data.json file on screen on selecting a particular country

Comment: there are multiple issues, you can't use the updated state right after calling setCountry, where should the details be displayed? how does the reducer look like?

Comment: @RameshReddy details should display on same page, here is the reducer
import { FETCH_COUNTRYLIST } from "../actions/types";

export default (state = [], action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case FETCH_COUNTRYLIST:
      return [...action.payload];
    default:
      return state;
  }
};

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `setCountry` (setting a state is async, so most probably it's not set yet when you map over the list), assign to a local variable (`let country`).

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Array.prototype.find` to find the matching country:

```
const selectHandleChange = ({ target: { value }}) => {
    // this will be updated in the next render
    setCountry(value)
    // so you should use value here
    setSelectedCountry(props.countries.find(country => country.id === value))
};
```

and pass a value prop (`country`) to the select element

```
<select className="select-opt" value={country} onChange={selectHandleChange}>
    {props.countries.map((country) => {-
        // pass a unique key
        return <option value={country.id} key={country.id}>{country.name}</option>;
    })}
</select>
```

in the JSX, you should render `selectedCountry`

```
<div className="form-labels">Selected:{JSON.stringify(selectedCountry)}</div>
```

Comment: I have tried to put this in existing code but nothing is rendering also tried to compare rank or continent instead of id still whole data is not rendering on screen. Below is the code.

Comment: @Akashkhanapurkar add `console.log`s in `selectHandleChange` function and see the values of `value` etc.